# Template specialisation with ptr-ref type, and specialisation rules

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Using MSVC 2010, I get the following behaviour:

```
template <class T> class Boogy
{
public:
    void Fn( T in )
    {
    }

    void Fn2( const T& in)
    {
    }
};

template <> void Boogy<int>::Fn( int in ) //builds ok
{
}

template <> void Boogy<int*>::Fn( int* in ) //builds ok
{
}

template <> void Boogy<int>::Fn2( const int& in ) //builds ok
{
}

template <> void Boogy<int*>::Fn2( const int*& in ) //DOES NOT BUILD
{
}

typedef int* intStar;
template <> void Boogy<intStar>::Fn2( const intStar& in ) //builds ok
{
}
```

Obviously, I've come up with a 'hack' to sort my issue out, but why is the hack necessary?  And should we be doing this at all?  The code base I'm in has dozens of instances where template classes have SOME specialisations of SOME of the member functions - not of the whole class.  A colleague is adamant that this isn't allowed.

TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `int * const &`. You have `T = int *`, so `const T = T const = int * const`.

Remember that `U const &` means "reference to constant `U`", and not "<s>constant reference to `U`</s>" — the latter doesn't make sense, since reference variables in C++ are *always* constant, i.e. cannot be reseated. In your case the `U` is a pointer-to-int, and not a pointer-to-const-int, which are two different types.

You can of course also add a separate specialization for `int const *`:

```
template <> void Boogy<int const *>::Fn2(int const * const & in) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Of course!  When you "read right to left" it suddenly makes sense.  Kerrek SB, are you the little green guy who got Luke's X-Wing out of the swamp?  ;-)  As for the question of performing specialisation on some members of a template class - that's ok, right?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: This is why I advertise going *against* the English of prepending `const` and always, systematically, put `const` *after* the type it qualifies. Only the inner type can be qualified *before*, it's too easy to mess it up :(

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yep, once you read right to left it seems obvious.  But I inherited ("inherited" as in someone else wrote it) the particular class and method I'm working with, the syntax was already in place.

Comment: @user1158692: "const is my integer, hmm...?"